# Data validations in firestore using firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My collection path is
`{Country}/{State}/{ZipCode}` where I'm storing some data in firestore as shown in the image pasted.
[image]

I've written a rule in firestore rules section like

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {   
            allow read;
       allow write: if request.resource.data.Quantity>0;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that the Quantity field in newly created document is positive using `firestore` rules. So I've written a rule the one shown above but it is not working. I can still write negative values to the `firestore`.
How can I create a rule to ensure that there are no negatives values under Quantity field of `firestore`?

Comment: Actually you rules do work. Maybe you didn't wait long enough before trying it after modifying them.

Comment: there is a simulator in firebase simulator to check if changes are working or not. Even publishing the rules need only a minute or so as per the firebase

Comment: See my answer. You can try the HTML page I provide: on my side it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the document path to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{Country}/{State}/{document=**} {   
allow read;       
allow write: if request.resource.data.Quantity > 0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, actually the rules shown by @SushantSomani in the question **do work**. Maybe he didn't wait long enough before trying it after modifying them.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec there is a simulator in firebase simulator to check if changes are working or not. Even publishing the rules need only a minute or so as per the firebase

Comment: @SushantSomani I didn't try with the simulator, but with a full HTML page that tries to write to Firestore with Quantity values like, 0, 2  and -1

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, your rules do work.

I have tried your rules with an HTML Page that tries to write documents with different `Quantity` values, see the code below. In the two cases (simple collection or sub-collection) only docs A and D are written to the database (and docs B and C generate an error).

Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.resource.data.Quantity > 0
    }
  }
}
```

HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: ".....",
            authDomain: ".....",
            databaseURL: ".....",
            projectId: "....."
        };

        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var theRef = db.collection('India').doc('Maharashtra').collection('411057');
        theRef.doc("A").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 1
        });

        theRef.doc("B").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 0
        });

        theRef.doc("C").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: -2
        });

        theRef.doc("D").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 2
        });


        var theRef = db.collection('India1');
        theRef.doc("A").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 1
        });

        theRef.doc("B").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 0
        });

        theRef.doc("C").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: -2
        });

        theRef.doc("D").set({
            name: "Mumbai",
            Quantity: 2
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- one should check if the field even exists
- before checking for it's integer value
- while the operations are `create` (and `update`):

resulting in a rule alike this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // match /{document=**} {
    // match /Orders/{document=**} { 
    match /{Country}/{State}/{PostCode}/{document=**} {  
      allow read;
      allow create: if request.resource.data.Quantity != null && int(request.resource.data.Quantity) > 0
      allow update: if request.resource.data.Quantity != null && int(request.resource.data.Quantity) > -1
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Firestore is a NoSql DB and it creates field if it does not exist. It is a JSON based DB

Comment: path to store data is clearly reflected in the image attached. Please try to write the firestore using rule given in other answer. You can then be sure that your answer is wrong. Thanks for the help BTW :)

Comment: but your answer made no changes to the document path, I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @SushantSomani added the full path & data validation rule for `create` & `update`... the other answer did not use the full path either - and it nevertheless worked, because sub-collection are matched by the `**` wildcard. while from a practical point of view, only `create` should be used, else one cannot update the value to `0`.

Comment: even improved on it, so that one can only create values `> 0` and not update to negative values, with `> -1` (in order to permit `0`, eg. in case the customer did decide otherwise)... using an `OrderId` as the name of the document might make sense, too - the `PostCode` already indicates the `State` (which makes this redundant data)... I mean, `match /Orders/{document=**}` would provide some more logical meaning to the structure, based upon the sample data provided.