# .orderByChild() is not working on Firebase (vue.js)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to sort my data by using .orderByChild, but the data are filter by the name of the node.

I added this on Firebase :

```
   "concerts": {
  ".indexOn": "expires"
}
```

And here is my code in my index.js file :

```
loadConcerts ({commit}) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  firebase.database().ref("concerts").orderByChild("expires").startAt(Date.now()/1e3).limitToFirst(7).once("value")
    .then((data) => {
      const concerts = []
      const obj = data.val()
      for (let key in obj) {
        concerts.push({
          expires: obj[key].expires,
          ...
        })
      }
      commit('setLoadedConcerts', concerts)
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
```

I also add this :

```
getters: {
loadedConcerts (state) {
  return state.loadedConcerts.sort((concertA, concertB) => {
    return concertA.expires > concertB.expires
  })
},
loadedConcert (state) {
  return (concertId) => {
    return state.loadedConcerts.find((concert) => {
      return concert.id === concertId
    }) 
   }
```

Maybe someone has a clue ? Thank you

Comment: Can you share your database structure and data sample?

Comment: Here is the database structure : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koplesh-1a17e.appspot.com/o/Capture%20d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran%202018-11-10%20a%CC%80%2010.08.47.png?alt=media&token=26b98903-760c-4517-9e48-89d4d9293370
Thanks for your help Renaud

Comment: @RenaudTarnec any idea ? Tell me if you need more stuff :)

Comment: What happens if you try your query with a simple JavaScript page? Make a simple HTML page similar to the one in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468815/data-validations-in-firestore-using-firebase-rules/52469533#52469533 and query your database as you have done `firebase.database().ref("concerts").orderByChild("expires").startAt(Date.now()/1e3).limitToFirst(7).once("value")
    .then((data) => {console.log(data.size)});` The HTML page can be stored on local on your PC and you open the file in a browser.

Comment: Hi, did you have time to test your query independently from the Vue.js code, as described above?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec nothing happened... here is a screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/ZsrJGMw (I just deleted firebase info for the screenshot) :)

Comment: So it seems you are having a problem with your query (and not Vue.js). What happens now if you query like  `firebase.database().ref("concerts").orderByChild("expires").limitToFirst(7).once("value").then((data) => {console.log(data.size)});`, so without the `startAt()`

Comment: Also, in the HTML page you don't need to do `var subscription = firebase.database()....` Just do directly `firebase.database()....`

Comment: And also take care that my initial comment contained an error with a space before `.then`  -> `.once("value") .then((data) => {console.log(data.size)});`.

Comment: something happened when I changed data.size by data ! Here is the html (http://koplesh.co/test.html), maybe you can inspect directly in the console ? Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Sorry, `data.size` was my mistake! I was mixing up the Realtime Database and Firestore.... But your query works, if you do `console.log(data.val());` it gives the results "1-pedrobooking": Object { concours: "2 places à gagner", concourslink: ..... And I think it is correctly sorted by `expires` value.

Comment: Great :) It is sort by key name. The trick I use is to name the key 1-xxx, 2-xxx, etc but I have to change the key name every day to order my list.

The conditions : ref("concerts").orderByChild("expires").startAt(Date.now()/1e3)
    .limitToFirst(7).once("value") are all accepted, but in fact my list is order by the name of the node

Comment: I'm not sure it is sort by key name. Because it is also **correctly** sorted by `expires` value. You should try to change a name in the database and see what returns the query

Comment: You can try here http://koplesh.co/test.html, i changed the value

Comment: You have changed the type of the `expires` from number to text with this new example. The records are sorted in Lexicographical order, and the sort seems correct. Can you add a key in the "concerts" node with a new value of `expires` that is a number and very low for example?

Comment: Here is another try (same url). I just give two value. The biggest value of expires is on first position. I would like the smallest on top.

Btw, if I give to "Andy Shauf" the smallest value, the order of the list isn't change.

Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate

Comment: See my answer! It took me some time to understand what was "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to list the value in the correct order (by `expires`) you should use the [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) method and not use directly `data.val()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.8/firebase.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: '......',
        authDomain: '......',
        databaseURL: '......',
        projectId: '......',
        storageBucket: '......'
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref('past')
        .orderByChild('expires')
        .startAt(Date.now() / 1e3)
        .limitToFirst(7)
        .once('value')
        .then(data => {
          const concerts = []
          data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.val());
            concerts.push({ id: element.key, expires: element.val().expires});
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: if you want to order with the reverse order, just store in another field the value of `-1*expires`

Comment: it works with the basic js file !!! Any idea of how to implement it on my vue file ? How can I thanks you more than here is this conversation Renaud ? You're amazing! Thanks so much for your time

Comment: like this it print my data many many times haha
.then(
        data => {
        const concerts = []
        const obj = data.val()
        data.forEach(element => {
        for (let key in obj) {
            concerts.push({
              id: key,
              expires: obj[key].expires
             ....
            })
          }
        })

Comment: Hi @PhilJones. Don't use `obj[key]`, just populate the `concerts` array with the `element` object. I've updated the answer.